# Appropriate way to start a server using the websockets lib and Python3.7

Tags: python, websocket, python-3.7

The [documentation for the library](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) shows that the following code should to the deal and it really works:

```
start_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

But the new Python-3.7 [asyncio library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) added the `asyncio.run` which *"runs the passes coroutine"* and *"should be used as a main entry point for asyncio programs."* Moreover, when looking at the [documentation for the `get_event_loop()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) used above it reads:

> Application developers should typically use the high-level 
>   asyncio functions, such as asyncio.run()...

I tried tho use the run in the following ways:

```
server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765)
asyncio.run(server)
```

from which I get a:

```
ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <websockets.server.Serve object at 0x7f80af624358>
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BaseEventLoop.create_server' was never awaited
```

Then I tried wrapping up the server in a Task by doing:

```
server = asyncio.create_task(websockets.serve(handle, 'localhost', 8765))
asyncio.run(server)
```

from which I get a:

```
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BaseEventLoop.create_server' was never awaited
```

Because of this last warning, I also tried:

```
async def main():
  server = asyncio.create_task(websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765))
  await server
asyncio.run(main())
```

To which I get the same error. What am I missing here? 
Moreover, if the **asyncio.run** does not start a running loop, what does it do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work. `wait_closed` is the awaitable that you've been looking for.

```
 async def serve():                                                                                           
      server = await websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765)
      await server.wait_closed()

 asyncio.run(serve())
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact it should be like this:
await (await server).wait_closed()
becasue server does not have wait_closed function.